# Why does Git show two commits when it merges?

Tags: git

Let's look at following scenario :

1. Two developers Clones the repo.
2. Dev 1 commits a change and then pushes.
3. Dev 2 commits a change and then tries to push, Git will say no you can't, you need to Pull, fair enough.
4. Dev 2 Pulls the change Dev 1 made
5. Now Dev 2 wants to push changes and Git says there are two commits to be pushed, one is the change he did himself and one is the merge but why two ? Why not just one were the merge information is contained in it ?

I am sure there is a good explanation :)

Comment: because a merge is a commit

Comment: Because developer 2 hasn't rebased their changes on top of developer 1s.

Answer (score 5):

Because, when Alice and Bob applied changes to the same commit, they created a fork on the road. Either Alice or Bob are gonna have to merge these two paths into one.

This is done via what's called a "merge commit" - which is usually empty *if* there's no conflict between Alice's and Bob's changes. If there are conflicts to be resolved, these will go into the "merge commit".

Alternatively, you could `git pull --rebase`, which will do a fetch+rebase, instead of fetch+merge.

This avoids creating a "merge commit". Instead, Bob will rewind his changes, pull Alice's changes, and then replay his changes on top of Alice's. If there are any conflicts, these will have to be resolved during the "replay" - and will be a part of Bob's commit.

Comment: i understand that but what what i am puzzled about is that the merge commit includes the same change that was made by Dev 2 even though there was no conflicts. I am ok with the merge commit if it was empty but now i can see two commits one with the real change with the real commit message and a merge commit with the SAME change but with the merge commit message. I think it's confusing but i guess i just have to live with it since i don't have a good explanation for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on [dcastro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22382962/1256452) a bit, after Alice "wins the push race" so that Bob has to bring in Alice's changes and combine hers with his...

Bob's two choices are "merge" and "rebase".

Merge is the most technically-accurate.  It tells person C (or D or E, or maybe all the way down to Zach), later, that Alice and Bob made their changes *at the same time*, probably without looking at what the other one was doing.

Bob's other option, to "rebase", consists of Bob figuring out what he did, undoing it, getting what Alice did, looking at that, and then redoing what Bob did.  (Using `git rebase` automates all this so that in *most* cases it's completely trivial.)  Later, Zach will think Alice did her thing first, and then Bob came along later and did his thing, working on top of what Alice did.

The question to consider here is whether Zach (or Cathy or Doug, etc) will actually *care* by then.  If not, Bob doing a rebase is probably the better option.  It makes things look simpler later.  It's just technically less accurate.

In more complex cases, it makes more sense to preserve the true history.  Let's say instead of just Alice and Bob, there's a whole team of people *led* by Alice and Bob.  And instead of just one commit each, the teams each make many commits.  At this point, for future dis-entangling of things if something has gone wrong somewhere, it makes much more sense to use a real merge, keeping the real history.  If, some time later, Zach needs the true history in order to track down a bug quickly—well, a rebase "rewrites history", obscuring the truth.